# Find all pairs of primes $p, q$ such that 3$p^2q+16pq^2$ equals to square of natural number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, square-numbers

Find all pairs of prime numbers $p, q$ such that 3$p^2q+16pq^2$ equals to square of natural number

My attempt: I've been trying to calculate equation through square root but now I'm stuck, please help

Comment: Did you try factoring?

Comment: Hint $$3p^2q +16pq^2=pq(3p+16q)$$

Comment: $p=2$ $q=3$ are only solutions

Comment: If neither of $p$ or $q$ equals $3$ then the number is of the form $4k+3$ and hence not a perfect square. If $p=3$ then highest power of $3$ dividing the number is $1$ and hence not a perfect square. So we try $q=3$. We see that $p^2+16p = (p+8)^2-64$ has to be a perfect square and hence $p+8=10$ or $p=2$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After factoring as $pq(3p+16q)=n^2$
We claim that p divides n and q divides n since both p and q divide $n^2$. Thus $n=k.pq$ for some kind belongs to natural numbers.

$3p+16q=k^2 pq 3/q+16/p=k^2$

from here we obtain p=2,q=3 and p and q are primes there are no more solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $3p^2q+16pq^2=k^2$

Since $q$ divides the LHS, it must divide $k^2$, and since $q$ is prime, it must be true that $q\mid k^2 \Rightarrow q^2\mid k^2$. Since $q^2\mid 16pq^2$, it follows that $q^2\mid 3p^2q \Rightarrow q\mid 3p^2$. But $q\not \mid p^2$, so $q\mid 3 \Rightarrow q=3$

Since $p$ divides the LHS, it must divide $k^2$, and since $p$ is prime, it must be true that $p\mid k^2 \Rightarrow p^2\mid k^2$. Since $p^2\mid 3p^2q$, it follows that $p^2\mid 16pq^2 \Rightarrow p\mid 16q^2$. But $p\not \mid q^2$, so $p\mid 16 \Rightarrow p=2$

This checks out, as $3\cdot 4\cdot 3+16\cdot 2\cdot 9=324=18^2$